# Cloud Functions Execution Tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Consider a client connected to Firebase Realtime Database. Then consider a scenario where I have `onCreate`, `onUpdate` Cloud Function triggers on some arbitrary `paths/nodes`.

Now I set some data via client on an arbitrarily chosen path `p1` which invokes `onCreate` trigger on `p1`. Let's say `onCreate` on `p1` updates some key-value pairs on path `p2` which invokes `onUpdate` trigger on `p2` and updates some key-value pairs on exact same path `p1` which invokes `onUpdate` trigger on `p1` as well. After that, all executions end.

Assuming all recursive triggers are taken care of, my questions are:

1) I want to print an execution tree that according to above example prints:

```
        p1(onCreate)
         /        \
  p2(onUpdate)  p1(onUpdate)
```

2) Is it even possible to do something like this with Cloud Functions or in general to track execution order?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either the context or the question: each write triggers the next function in your sequence as far as I can see. But the `onUpdate` on `p1` sounds recursive to me, so I hope you have a clear stop criterium for that.

Comment: Sure. infinitely recursive cases are taken care of. I have considered `onUpdate` on `p1` because it "will execute" and it will be one of the leaf nodes of the overall tree formed. Pardon my English.

Comment: If English is a problem, I recommend showing code. I honestly am having a hard time parsing the problem. Maybe somebody else can do better, but otherwise I'd recommend sharing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).